# Android : View SQLite Database

Tags: android

I'm running Android Studio 1.3 and working on tutorial app. I'm using GenyMotion for testing purpose. I have written some code to create a database. Now I want to see whether that database has been created or not. If yes then where it is stored. In Eclipse we used to have DDMS Monitor but no such thing is present in Android Studio. So How to do so?

Comment: DDMS Monitor is also available in Android Studio, Please check under 'window' tab

Comment: check answer that i posted.

Comment: I am not the guy voting down your question, I have only less reputation, if I voting down  your intelligent questions, I will loss 2 of my reputation, thanks

Comment: salih dude that was not for you. This was for the smartest people on the planet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is using Android Device Monitor to get the  database file and SQLite DataBase Browser to view the file while still  using Android Studio to program android.

1) Run and launch database app with Android emulator from Android Studio.

2) Run Android Device Monitor. How to run?; Go to [your_folder] > sdk >tools. You can see monitor.bat in that folder. shift + right click inside the folder and select "Open command window here". This action will launch command prompt. type monitor and Android Device Monitor will be launched.(There are other ways to open this too. Search it)

3) Select the emulator that you are currently running. Then Go to data>data>[your_app_package_name]>databases

4) Click on the icon (located at top right corner) (hover on the icon  and you will see "pull a file from the device")  and save anywhere you  like

5) Launch SQLite DataBase Browser. Drag and drop the file that you just saved into that Browser. (You can view the database using any SQLite browser of your choice)

6) Go to Browse Data tab and select your table to view.

[image]

[image]